# How to install the latest versions of a group of NPM packages so that they are compatible to each other?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm, npm-install

I would like to install all the npm packages from this list:

`@angular/common, @angular/compiler, @angular/core, @angular/forms, @angular/http, @angular/platform-browser, @angular/platform-browser-dynamic, @angular/router, @angular/router-deprecated, @angular/upgrade, systemjs, core-js, reflect-metadata, rxjs, zone.js, angular2-in-memory-web-api, es6-promise, es6-shim, jquery, bootstrap`

Yes, it's quite a bit of packages. So how do I install the latest possible versions that are supposed to work with each other (assuming I can trust the declared dependency versions in npm package metadata)?

Comment: I don't have a solution to this but ideally I always install the latest of all and then if I get any version specific error then I downgrade which ever is required. But your question has a good point.

Answer (score 0):

How do I:

1. go to [Quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html)
2. scroll to [configuration files](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html#!#add-config-files)
3. copy/paste from tab "package.json" (see "dependencies" section)